# How do I display an image in imageview from an SQLite database when in database I saved an URI to this image?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my application I take a photo and this captured photo shows in an imageview. When I click 'save', this photo is saved to the database (to the database I save a URL to this photo).

And now, I want to display my save image in another imageview. How can I do this? How can I display an image from database in an imageview?

Comment: Please share the minimal form of the code, to expect precise help to your question.

Comment: Can you please post your code of whatever you tried.

Comment: You should save photo in file system and save URI to that image in SQLite.

Comment: Hey @AnnaWoźniak do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V or tick looking button next to the answer, it helps future Stack Overflow readers, and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not given the code, so I can't help but give you some general answer for your question.

You need to retrieve the URI from your database and after retrieving the URI from database, you need to parse it into URI format, using a code like this:

```java
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("Data you got from db");
```

After that you can show it in ImageView, using a code like this:

```java
imageView.setImageURI(mUri);
```

Comment: I gave a few photoes of my code. It's below pavel's comment.

Comment: @AnnaWoźniak please do not answer your question with details of your question, you can edit your question for that.

Comment: @AnnaWoźniak if you have saved the uri and are able to retrieve it perfectly, use the above code to make string uri again and set it to your imageView.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Always using Glide / Picasa library for loading image to ImageView.

`Glide.with(context).load(new File(URI.getPath())).into(imageView)`

If you are storing URI in a database as a String, then parse String to URI. 
Then try this code.

For Glide Library, you need to add a dependency. Then it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Load the URI from database and set it into the imageview. Before that you have to parse it.

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("Your URI");
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```